# sending NaN in json

Tags: python, json, serialization, nan

I am trying to encode an array which contains floats and `NaN` into JSON string from Python using `json.dumps()`.

But the encoded JSON string is not being decoded successfully in PHP. Is the `NaN` causing this problem? How can I work around this situation?

Comment: What does the outputted JSON look like? NaN isn't a native data type in Python, so I'm surprised it works at all.

Comment: @Daniel: Actually, if you do `float("nan")`, you can get it. And calling `json.dumps(float("nan"))` gives you "NaN".

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`json.dumps` has an `allow_nan` parameter, which defaults to True.

NaN, Infinity and -Infinity are not part of JSON, but they are standard in Javascript, so they're commonly used extensions. If the recipient can't handle them, set `allow_nan=False`. But then you'll get ValueError when you try to serialise NaN.

Comment: How to handle `ValueError` to serialise numpy `Nan` value??

Comment: But why oh why make the default behaviour of a JSON library to output something that isn't JSON??? :@

Comment: It wasn't my decision, but I think the `json` module in Python was added around the same time as `JSON.parse` in browsers (Python 2.6 in 2008, ES5 in 2009). So probably a lot of people were just eval-ing JSON in Javascript, which would naturally accept NaN & Infinity, so someone went for 'practicality beats purtiy'. Once you've made a decision like that, you may well stick to it for compatibility, even if it later becomes clear that the other way would be better.

Answer (score 46):

The simplejson package on which Python's standard json package is based moves more quickly, and handles this situation. `NaN` is not valid JSON, and the `ignore_nan` flag will handle correctly all `NaN` to `null` conversions.

```
import simplejson as json
json.dumps(thing, ignore_nan=True)
```

The `default` parameter will allow simplejson to parse your datetimes correctly.

```
json.dumps(response, ignore_nan=True, default=datetime.datetime.isoformat)
```

simplejson can be installed with pip.

```
pip install simplejson
```

Answer (score 33):

NaN is not a valid JSON symbol, see the spec at http://json.org/

Your encoder should probably have encoded the NaN as `null` instead.

Comment: You will have to fix that, look at the manual http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#basic-usage