# Python json dump not read by javascript JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to read a json file generated through `json.dump` module in python and reading it in a javascript using `JSON.parse`. However, for some of the json dumps the javascript is throwing an exception for invalid literal. Does anyone know why this might happen or what should I do to prevent this?

> Browsers: Chrome/Firefox; python ver: 2.7

EDIT1: based on the comment supplying some code

1) json dumped using

```
import json
json.dump(<python-dict>, open(<filename>,'w'), encoding='utf-8')``
```

2) Code read using

- `d3.json`
  Output: a syntax error is thrown before the callback is called.
- `JSON.parse`
  Outputs: invalid json

EDIT2: it may be relevant , the json dump is pretty large , around 24M uncompressed.

Comment: Could you post some relevant code please, easier to debug that way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of completing the circle I found out the problem and the corresponding fix.

Firstly the problem:

The problem wasn't about `not closing the file` as some answers suggested or about the size being too big (as I thought initially). The problem was that  my data before the `json.dump` part contained NAN's and by default `json.dump` (see [json documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)) either allow nan's to be 'serialized' or throws an error (when 'allow_nan=False'). However, according to ECMA-262 NAN's are not allowed and hence the jquery json read was failing to read the dump.

The solution:

Use `simplejson` and use `ignore_nan` with it. The corrected code snippet should be

```
import simplejson
simplejson.dump(<python-dict>, open(<filename>,'w'), encoding='utf-8', ignore_nan=True)
```

Credits: [sending NaN in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601812/sending-nan-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the file, which will likely result in an incomplete file when you're trying to read that again.

How about

```
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(myobject, outfile)
```

Comment: sorry about that.. its a typo... i did remember to give the object