# Passing a NaN from Python through Request to Javacscript

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, nan

I have a pandas array with np.NaN's in it that I convert to a dictionary for JSON

`json_data = {"freq" : list(df["Data"])}`

I get ready to load to a web page via flask jsonify

```
@dashboard.route('/command', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def command():
[...]
return jsonify(json_data)
```

and on the javascript side I get ready to read it.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/command',
            type: 'POST', 
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(msg) {
              if (!msg.error) {
                updatePlot(msg);
              }
              else {
                alert(msg.error);
              }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("There has been an error retrieving your data: \n\n" + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
              $("#update-plot").prop('disabled', false);  // Re-enable button
              $("#update-plot-loading").addClass('invisible');  // Hide loading animation
            }
```

And that is where it dies if I load that web page. It says that it has a bad token "N" in the json. If I replace the NaN's before trying to send, e.g.

```
df["Data"].replace(np.NaN, -999.999)
```

and all is fine and the javascript can continue. I'm aware that the NaN's should be "null" on the javascript side, so what I do at the moment (ugh) is then convert the -999.999's to "null"... But gosh, shouldnt there be a way to send missing data directly?

Any suggestions? I have tried many combinations of NaN, "NaN", None, etc. But maybe I missed one. I checked the output of jsonify on the python said and it seems to be a valid response to send over.

Thanks, T.

Comment: `NaN` cannot be encoded as JSON. It's not part of the syntax.

Comment: If you think about it, `NaN` really isn't "information"; it's not even a specific value. JSON was intended as a data serialization system, so it's arguable that `NaN` isn't really useful data. (The contrary is also arguable, I admit. But that's the way it is.)

Comment: Hm. like white spaces not being information either :-)

Comment: So it seems like JSON is perfectly happy with null. So maybe if I string replace all NaN's to null it will go through?

Comment: Yea, it's up to how your application works. JSON is very limited; for example Date values, which are clearly pretty important in a lot of software, have no standard representation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601812/sending-nan-in-json

Answer (score 1):

Aha. Progress, sort of. At least on the Flask side, maybe not Ajax. Consider a Pandas with some `np.Nan` in it... Convert to a dict or whatever and then call render_template

```
s = render_template('dashboard/dashboard_horizontal.html', 
        average_data = average_data)
```

This is where the damage gets done.... but it is fixable with

```
s = s.replace("nan", "NaN")      #this is dumb but works!!
```

A related problem ocurse with `false` in json. When you read it into Python, the parser conveniently turns it into `False`. Except now you created problem on the Javascript side, but it is also fixable the same way.

```
s = s.replace("False", "false")      #this is dumb too
```

I dont know if there are some keywords that could be passed to render_template to do this automatically?

Comment: Well, this only works if the **only** occurrences of `nan`/`False` etc are the values... might work in your case but wont work in general

Comment: Agreed. Although the worst case scenario is words like "inanimate" would mysteriously turn into iNaNimate. But at least it wouldnt crash the browser.

Comment: Ha!! GACy20, I thought you might appreciate this.... Just had a customer complain that the browser not working, turns out I had created the word MataiNaNce in a table that was then subsequently not matching the word "maintainance".. Pretty much exactly as you anticipated...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, an I have an Ajax solution for NaN too, which is the JSON5 idea explained here : [How to parse JSON string containing "NaN" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228651/how-to-parse-json-string-containing-nan-in-node-js) . Specifically, dont use dataType json, go with 'text' and do the parsing by hand.

```
          $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/command',
            type: 'POST',   
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'text',            // it was 'json'
            //async: false,
            success: function(msg) {
              if (!msg.error) {
                var data = json5.parse(msg);  // json5 so much more friendly
                updatePlot(data);
              }
              else {
                alert(msg.error);
              }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Error:\n\n" + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
              $("#update-plot").prop('disabled', false);  // Re-enable button
              $("#update-plot-loading").addClass('invisible');   
            }
          });
        }
```